# INSERT / UPDATE with a condition on a different table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table of users and a junction table that states which user can do what.

For example I want to insert / update a new user only if the user making that action is present in my junction table.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Probably something along the lines of: `insert into ... select ... where exists (...)`  but your question does not contain enough details to really answer that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name

I have 2 tables, `foo` and `bar`. when I want to insert into `foo` I want to also make a check to see if something exists in `bar` before making that insert.

Answer (score 0):

As it relates to the insertion of data in the users table, you cannot have data in the junction table about a user that does not exist.

As for the `UPDATE`, you can use the SQL `WHERE EXISTS` statement to check the junction table. For example, given that the `users` table has a column name `id` (Primary Key) and the junction table has the foreign key `user_id` for the `users` table:

```
UPDATE users u 
   SET col_1 = 'val_1' 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM junction_table WHERE user_id = u.id)
```

Comment: @chubaka Data on a user cannot be in the junction table if the user does not exist. You need to insert the user first before any data related to that user can be inserted in the junction table.

Comment: @chubaka Could you explain a bit then because databases are not designed to function the way you are requesting.

Comment: I have a manager, he manages users and also creates them, he himself is a user, the distinction between being a manager and not being one is by being in my junction table named managers, once a manager tries to insert a new user I want to make a check and see if that manager is really in fact a manager, which requires me to look up the junction table before I insert that new user. It's just a simple conditional check before making an insert, there's no way this sort of thing is impossible.

Comment: @chubaka Then I misunderstood your question. That would be a different process. You will need to do the check (possible using a `SELECT` before doing the `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. Also you might want to explain just that situation in your question and put the structure of the two tables.

Answer (score -1):

IF EXISTS(SELECT top 1 1  from Junctiontable Where UserId=YourID)
BEGIN
    INSERT/UPDATE STATEMENT HERE ....
END

Comment: Please add more info of code, output.. what you want and what you get. The name of your tool and its version.

Comment: IF EXISTS(SELECT top 1 1 from Junctiontable Where UserId=YourID)  --Condition on different table
BEGIN 
INSERT/UPDATE STATEMENT HERE .... -- INSERT\UPdate on required table
END

SQL Server 2014